# catch all ajax responses?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

is there any way to catch all responses from an ajax request whether it is coming from different libraries like jQuery, prototype or just the plain vanilla XMLHttpRequest object?

I'd like to be able to ADD to any handler that is already existing and not destroy any handler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think each lib needs an own handler.
With jQuery you can set global handlers: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Comment: can't need a solution that will receive ajax responses coming from arbitrary requests.